# the process can not access the file bin\debug because it is being used another process

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging, pos, locked-files

Unable to copy file `obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe` to `bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe`. The process cannot access the file `bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe` because it is being used by another process.  WindowsFormsApp1.

> Could not copy "obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe" to
>   "bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.
>   The file is locked by: "WindowsFormsApp1 (11808)" WindowsFormsApp1

Hello guys what can I do with this...? I'm used to visual studio pro version 2019. I've tried and research many resources everywhere still not find and desperate to being now. Please help what can I do for know. I'm working on a pos software project right now and having a problem. When I download getting set up completed with warnings that couldn't install `Microsoft.visualstudio.aspnet45.feature`.

Having any solution?

Comment: `locked by: "WindowsFormsApp1` The app is still running, or has previously crashed but did not fully close. Find the process in Task Manager and end it, or `taskkill` it from a cmd prompt.

Comment: thanks it works for fully close the windowsformsapp1 condition:) but what is the problem with "set up completed with warnings that couldn't install microsoft.visualstudio.aspnet45.feature" --> what the primary issue from download??

Comment: You should really ask one single question per post. Don't know about aspnet45, but you'll better your chances at an answer if you include the full details - exact versions, error codes, logfiles etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I didn't know about it:)

Answer (score -1):

> When I download getting set up completed with warnings that couldn't
>   install Microsoft.visualstudio.aspnet45.feature.

Try these steps：

**1)** make sure that Windows Update option turns on and if there is any update, please update it.

**2)** run CMD as **Administrator** and then input the following command: `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

and

`DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`

**Note that** it might take several minutes for the command to complete.

**3)** Run the following command: `sfc /scannow` and `sc config trustedinstaller start=auto`

**4)** reboot the system.

**5)** turn off any any anti-virus or any anti-malware

**6)** then Repair the install from the VS Installer

> the process can not access the file bin\debug because it is being used
>   another process

For this problem, you should shut down any `WindowsFormsApp1.exe` Instance on Task Manager and then restart it just as **dxiv** said.

Comment: Thanks, After input the all DISM.exe command I have in command window message that is "An error occured while attempting to start the servicing process for the image located at C:\. For more information, review the log file.

Comment: And The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

And after I was typing the C:\WIndows\....log created new dism - notepad window included dism infos to my desktop. What would you want to let me do after this?

Comment: Since you got this issue, please install [Windows 10 deployment scenarios and tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/windows-deployment-scenarios-and-tools) and then use the latest dism.exe under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\DISM>` to test again.